# In purrr::map, after group_split; How can I create a named list from one column in a list of tibbles using elements from another column as names?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I am struggling with referring values from one column in a list of tibbles to create a named list from another column, using purrr:map functions. Any help would be appreciated!

Reproducible example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

v1 <- rep(letters[1:10], 3)
v2 <- rep(LETTERS[1:3], 10)
v3 <- rnorm(30)

t <- tibble(v1, v2, v3)

t2 <- t %>%
  group_split(v2) %>%
  map(~.x %>% modify_at("v3", ~set_names(.x, "v1")))
```

#I want to use values from 'v1' as names in named list (with values from 'v3'). Does not work!
#Caused by error in `set_names()`:
#! The size of `nm` (30) must be compatible with the size of `x` (10).

> t2[[1]]$v3

Comment: I cannot reproduce. To me, your code runs without errors.

Answer (score 3):

You want this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

t2 <- t %>%
  group_split(v2) %>%
  map(~ set_names(.x$v3, .x$v1))

named_vector1 <- t2[[1]]

t2
named_vector1
```

```
t2
[[1]]
           a            d            g            j            c            f            i            b            e            h 
 0.125768861 -2.220447502  0.362207797 -0.431830760  0.805455774  0.321546114 -0.827056265 -1.224760040  0.008170793 -0.783951939 

[[2]]
          b           e           h           a           d           g           j           c           f           i 
 1.12432305  0.68200700  0.58304763  0.04008495  0.91584028  0.86049333 -0.68042443 -0.23048205 -1.71889470 -1.03430104 

[[3]]
          c           f           i           b           e           h           a           d           g           j 
 0.61758822 -0.85423696 -1.74924210 -1.25383234 -0.84207937 -0.08451343 -1.42264178 -0.05806052  0.16760775  1.02964839 

> named_vector1
           a            d            g            j            c            f            i            b            e            h 
 0.125768861 -2.220447502  0.362207797 -0.431830760  0.805455774  0.321546114 -0.827056265 -1.224760040  0.008170793 -0.783951939
```

Comment: Thanks, this is works perfectly! I guess my confusion is partly related to the need to use '.x$' in addition to the variable name, while often this is not necessary in the tidyverse(..?)

Answer (score 2):

Use `deframe` instead:

```
t %>% 
  group_split(v2, .keep = FALSE) %>%
  map(deframe)

[[1]]
         a          d          g          j          c          f          i          b          e          h 
 0.6980159 -1.0698884  0.9248987 -1.1137024  0.1976790  1.3918101 -0.9205889 -0.5747299  0.3631078 -1.0331644 

[[2]]
         b          e          h          a          d          g          j          c          f          i 
-1.8588877 -1.1719188  1.0250352 -1.0637924  0.4415625  1.6617184  1.1814334  0.4438979 -0.4813941  0.6253411 

[[3]]
         c          f          i          b          e          h          a          d          g          j 
-0.4879884 -0.9201849  0.5024855  1.3433119  1.0420189 -1.3437926  1.4564144  0.2931938 -1.1779862  0.8228465
```

---

in Base R:

```
with(t, split(setNames(v3,v1),v2))
$A
         a          d          g          j          c          f          i          b          e          h 
 0.6980159 -1.0698884  0.9248987 -1.1137024  0.1976790  1.3918101 -0.9205889 -0.5747299  0.3631078 -1.0331644 

$B
         b          e          h          a          d          g          j          c          f          i 
-1.8588877 -1.1719188  1.0250352 -1.0637924  0.4415625  1.6617184  1.1814334  0.4438979 -0.4813941  0.6253411 

$C
         c          f          i          b          e          h          a          d          g          j 
-0.4879884 -0.9201849  0.5024855  1.3433119  1.0420189 -1.3437926  1.4564144  0.2931938 -1.1779862  0.8228465
```